# Replace high-low probable values with 1-0 in data frame using loop

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Sam = c("N1","N2","N3","N4","N5")
S1 = c(.7,.3,.4,.8,.2)
S2 = c(.6,.5,.6,.9,.9)
S3 = c(.5,.7,.8,.6,.6)
S4 = c(.6,.8,.5,.4,.8)
S5 = c(.9,.2,.6,.4,.5)
S6 = c(.8,.8,.7,.2,.7)
S7 = c(.8,.6,.7,.5,.6)
Predicted.SR = c(6,4,5,3,5)
df = data.frame(Sam,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,Predicted.SR)
```

Data frame df:

```
Sam S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  Predicted.SR
N1  0.7 0.6 0.5 0.6 0.9 0.8 0.8 6
N2  0.3 0.5 0.7 0.8 0.2 0.8 0.6 4
N3  0.4 0.6 0.8 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7 5
N4  0.8 0.9 0.6 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.5 3
N5  0.2 0.9 0.6 0.8 0.5 0.7 0.6 5
```

What i would like to do is: first,  rank all the probabilities in each row (decreasing order). Then I would like to replace the high probable values of the species (up to predicted.SR, e.g. up to 6 for row N1) with 1, and replace the low probable values with 0.

The following is the new data frame that i would like to have.

```
Sam S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  Pred.SR
N1  1   1   0   1   1   1   1   6
N2  0   0   1   1   0   1   1   4
N3  0   1   1   0   1   1   1   5
N4  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   3
N5  0   1   1   1   0   1   1   5
```

Could anyone help me writing a loop for this?

Comment: So, what exactly are you having trouble with when you try to do it?

Comment: thank Erocoar, actually i would like to write a loop for that, but i could not. Could you help me write/or give any example?

Comment: Please show your attempt - it is much easier to not start from scratch, and if you don't even show an attempt it is very difficult to know how much detail you will need. From you question it is unclear if you know how to write a for loop, or apply a function to every column because you give no indication of what you have tried and where you are stuck. For the first sep, have you tried using `rank()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out <- cbind(
  Sam = df$Sam,
  t(apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) {
  sorted <- sort(x[1:(length(x)-1)], decreasing = TRUE)
  sorted[1:x[length(x)]] <- 1; sorted[(x[length(x)]+1):length(sorted)] <- 0
  sorted <- sorted[sort(names(sorted), decreasing = FALSE)]
  return(sorted)})),
  Predicted.SR = df$Predicted.SR)
```

This would be a possibility .. for each row, first sort based on the probabilities and change to 1 and 0. Then revert to original format by sorting based on the column names. You might want to think about what happens when two edge cases have the same probability ?

Comment: thank you very much Erocoar. It would be very interesting if you could provide a clue in the case of when two edge cases have the same probability.

Comment: I'm not sure how, I have no idea where your data comes from and what you are trying to do with it ;)